# Formula for finding distance to a line segment?

Tags: java, swing

I need some help with a formula or bit of code for finding the distance to the closest point in a line segment. Effectively, the "distance from the line segment" is going to be used as a sort of "bonding box", so that a user can click relatively close to a line, and it count as clicking on that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Swing, then you should be able to use [`Line2D.ptSegDist(Point2D)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptSegDist%28java.awt.geom.Point2D%29) or its various overloads to do all the math for you.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/) explains how to find the closest point on a line.

It also includes a [sample implementation in Java](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/DistancePoint.java).

Comment: @Derek The page I linked to provides the formula you ask for. But you should definitely use `ptSegDist` from Louis Wasserman's answer if you can. Never write code you don't have to. Code you write = potential bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Java function

```
public static
double
distanceToSegment( final R3 v, final R3 a, final R3 b )
```

full gist:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ca967360b5a6613604c416fe50d2d87

from open source library
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geokarambola/

Comment: try posting actual code instead of just a gist link